# Создавать новые массивы или fill'ить уже существующие?

Tags: c++, массивы

Предположим, что у нас есть массив A, который уже отслужил своё и больше не нужен. Мне нужен новый массив B, при этом той же размерности что и A. Мне создавать новый B, или мне стоит наполнить A, к примеру, 0 с помощью функции fill?

Comment: Зависит от того, что необходимо для программы. 
Для больших данных это экономит память, но может затруднить понимание кода

Comment: Освободить память с под старого массива и создать новый. Это для большего понимания кода. А если прога аля 2 класса и только для вас...то можете и перезаполнять

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а если брать во внимание не память, а скорость?

Comment: Просто по памяти можно и простое освобождение использовать, но вопрос, что быстрее: освобождение памяти и выделение новой или простое обнуление массива?

Comment: А может и обнулять не нужно?

Comment: @avp обнулять нужно, потому что алгоритм завязан на том, что дефолтные значения массива 0

Comment: Если обнуление важно с т.з. алгоритма, то это время также надо учитывать и при создании нового. Вообще-то, достаточно очевидно, что переиспользование ранее выделенной памяти быстрее. С точки зрения понятности -- что же, в качестве имен массивов можно ведь использовать указатели на одну и ту же память (в т.ч. статическую или в стеке, не обязательно выделять ее по `new`)

Comment: @avp т.е. время на освобождение старой и выделение новой памяти больше, чем время, которое понадобится для обнуления существующего массива. Даже если брать в расчёт размер массивов?

Comment: @ProstoCoder,  Неужели вы всерьез считаете, что обнуление выделяемой новой памяти бесплатно?

Comment: @avp я считаю(знаю), что выделение памяти НАМНОГО быстрее, чем обнуление. при этом как при малых размерах массивов, так и при огромных.

Comment: вот только выделенную память наверно нужно будет обнулить... да, она случайно при старте программы может быть обнуленная, но это не гарантируется. Более того, если переиспользовать через создание-удаление, то чудным образом менеджер памяти может подсунуть ту же память...

Comment: @ProstoCoder, в таком случае вы получаете ее без гарантий обнуления. А те страницы, что ядро (если речь о Линуксе) впервые выдает прикладной программе (они в самом деле обнулены) реально обнуляются в рамках времени этого прикладного процесса (т.е. ничего бесплатного в системе нет. Справедливости ради -- обнуление страниц в ядре может быть быстрее, чем в memset в прикладной программе)

Comment: @avp вот блин, вы правы, я действительно при проверке не учёл того, что при создании нового массива по дефолту в нём находятся "рандомные" значения...

Comment: @avp, но ведь вызов `new` и так обнуляет массив?

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546745/7286264

Comment: @avp, ой)) Но если там не примитивный тип, то конструктор же вызывается?

Comment: @Qwertiy, конечно вызывается. Впрочем, в данном вопросе ТС ничего не сказал о типах

Comment: Переиспользование памяти, конечно, быстрее немного, но совсем немного. А вот сильно замедлить может наполнение через push_bach, emplace_back, emplace, insert, если зармер массива известен заранее. В этом случае стоит сразу выделить необходимую память. По поводу же переиспользования, стоит писать как понятнее, выделение новой 1 раз вряд-ли станет узким местом вашей программы, а уже потом смотреть, если она медленно работает, то где именно и оптимизировать.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уверены на все 100% что данные в массиве "А" вам не нужны, то для экономии памяти можно обнулить и заполнить его заново